# What is the correct encoding for the Windons Shell Extension "Property Description Schema" file?

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, shell-extensions

I have a library package that I am using to create a Windows Shell Extension, and in particular the code needed for properties of files. I need my project to support Unicode files and text, so I compile the project with Unicode support, but when I register the dll with regsvr32, the library package is auto-generating the .propdesc file but it appears to be writing the file out as UTF-16. When it does this, the properties don't appear to be getting correctly registered to the indexer. However, if I compile my dll as Multi-byte rather than Unicode, then this file is written and registered in ASCII encoding, which then works.

Since the .propdesc file is a XML document with the header stating "UTF-8" I would think that the encoding must be UTF-8, but I know that Windows doesn't always honor this thought. So does anyone know if the indexer will accept Property Description Scheme files in UTF-16, or will it only accept UTF-8/ASCII encoded files?

Comment: Wait a minute. The .propdesc file contains UTF-16 but its header claims to be UTF-8? Isn't that the entire problem?

Comment: One would think so, but I have seen other Windows API handle the files in both encoding despite what the XML says, because Windows doesn't always follow the standards. :) Plus the issue is that the entire file, including the XML header has been encoded at UTF-16. So really what good is the header anyway?

Comment: Sounds like another entry for _Old New Thing_. Really, the fact that some Windows component accidentily understands broken XML doesn't mean that _all_ Windows components will parse _all_ broken XML.

Comment: Well, I have reported the issue to the company that makes the library package, so I guess I will just have to wait to hear back from them.

Comment: Just create a post-build step to strip the `<?xml charset` processing instruction and you are good to go.